# Why does this grep command throws error?

Tags: regex, grep

If I use this command it works as I need:

```
grep -o -e "{{ *[-_[:alnum:]]\+"
```

But if I use this one it throws error

```
grep -o -e "{{ *[_-[:alnum:]]\+"
```

Same as this one:

```
grep -o -e "{{ *[[:alnum:]-_]\+"
```

And this other:

```
grep -o -e "{{ *[[:alnum:]-\_]\+"
```

Seems that the [] from the RegExp can't start nor end with _

Why?

Error is:

> grep: Invalid range end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is related to the hypen `-`: `0-9` means `0123456789`. But what is the meaning of `_-[:alnum:]`? Putting `-` as the first character disables this special meaning, so the first regexp works as expected.

Comment: Strange, I thought you could omit the problem by escaping the `-` (works in Perl), but no matter how many backslashes I prepend it with, the error persists, even with `grep -E`. Tested with GNU grep 2.5.3.

Comment: yeah it must be that, I didn't realised. Thanks for asnwering!